# Pandas merge conflict rows by counts?

Tags: pandas

A conflict row is that two rows have same feature but with different label, like this:

```
feature label
  a       1
  a       0
```

Now, I want to merge these conflict rows to only one label getting from their counts. If I have more `a 1`, then `a` will be labeled as `1`. Otherwise, `a` should be labeled as `0`.

I can find these conflicts by `df1=df.groupy('feature', as_index=Fasle).nunique(),df1 = df1[df1['label]==2]'` , and their value counts by `df2 = df.groupby("feature")["label"].value_counts().reset_index(name="counts")`.

But how to find these conflic rows and their counts in **one Dataframe** (`df_conflict = ?`), and then **merge** them by counts, (`df_merged = merge(df)`)?

Lets take `df = pd.DataFrame({"feature":['a','a','b','b','a','c','c','d'],'label':[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]})` as example.

```
    feature  label
0       a      1
1       a      0
2       b      0
3       b      1
4       a      1
5       c      0
6       c      0
7       d      1
```

`df_conflict` should be :

```
feature  label counts
   a      1      2
   a      0      1
   b      0      1
   b      1      1
```

And `df_merged` will be:

```
feature  label 
  a      1      
  b      0         
  c      0      
  d      1
```

Comment: I need two different dataframe, `df_conflict` for showing the conflit rows and their counts, and a new `df` for the merged result.

Comment: Please see my newest version of question. It seems that I cannot paste code with muliple line in comment. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what means `and then merge them by counts, (df_merged = merge(df))?`, is possible explain more?

Comment: Surely. `df_conflict` seems a little different with my thoughts. It should only contains the conflict rows. Meanwhile, I am confuse of how you get `df_merged`. It looks like just `drop_duplicates` by a given column. How the value_counts affects?

Comment: In previous answer if use `value_counts` values are sorted by default, so first row for each group has maximum count. Added answer for second part of answer.

Comment: I got it. A lot of details I droped in makes me not have a flash of this idea. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first filter groups with count of unique values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) before [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('feature')['label'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
df_conflict = df1.groupby('feature')['label'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')

print (df_conflict)
  feature  label  count
0       a      1      2
1       a      0      1
2       b      0      1
3       b      1      1
```

For second get `feature` with labels by maximum occurencies:

```
df_merged  = df.groupby('feature')['label'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
print (df_merged)
  feature  label
0       a      1
1       b      0
2       c      0
3       d      1
```